# IE8 inherits width of parent element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want a box with at least two elements inside and every element should be as big as the biggest element. This works fine in FF/Safari but not IE.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>whatever</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      display: table;
      width: 250px;
      border: 1px solid red;
          padding: 10px;
    }

        .top {
          border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        .bottom {
          border: 1px solid green;
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="top">
          top
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          bottom
          oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

**Update:**

Giving .top a width of 100% does not work. A div (or block element) does have 100% by default. It should be that big anyway.

**Update2:**

Removing display: table doesn't change anything.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add the strict doctype to your page, otherwise IE is in quirks mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

With that at the top of the file it works in IE8 for me.

### EDIT

Well on further research I'm pretty sure IE8's table support is completely buggy. I added a wrapper element on the text so that I could mimic a table exactly (code below). Then I put an actual table below that. The table works exactly as you want it, but the equivalent in divs does not. I tried other elements like spans but it still doesn't work.

In short: use ordinary tables if you can, or rethink your layout.

Here's the code I used. The two "tables" should be exactly the same, save a little padding here and there:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>whatever</title>
  <style>
    .box {
        display: table;
        width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .top {
        display: table-row;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .bottom {
        display: table-row;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .top .cell {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .bottom .cell {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid green;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="top">
          <div class="cell">top</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="cell">bottom
          oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br><br>

      <table style="border: 1px solid red; display: table;width: 250px">
      <tr style="display: table-row;">
          <td style="border: 1px solid blue; display: table-cell;">top</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display: table-row;">
          <td style="border: 1px solid green; display: table-cell;">bottom
          oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes for me, too. But I'm not able to change the doctype. I have to stick with: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Comment: You can change all the HTML and CSS code but not the doctype? Why?

Comment: who said I can change all CSS and HTML? =)

Comment: Who said you couldn't? *Certainly not you.* How are we supposed to know what to suggest if you omit **vital** information like the fact you're unable to change some things? :/

Answer (score 0):

Give both elements `width:100%` or `display:table-row`.

This is happening probably because you have `display: table;` for parent div. `display: table` tells the element to display as a table. Nested elements should be displayed as `table-row` and `table-cell`, mimicking the good old TR's and TD's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether width is an inherited attribute for div.

To fix the issue, set the width of `.top` to `100%`.